# Step for 5.3 version of solr

Tags: apache, solr

I am new in apache solr 5.3. All the tutorial related to solr are explained in 4 version. Which have (`Solr.war`).
Can somebody explain the step for 5.3 version of solr?

Comment: are you looking for installation steps?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're looking for, but there's a lot of info on the Web regarding Solr 5.3. For example, here's a quickstart guide from the Solr site: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html

Comment: guys i am looking for step to installing solr... now i got it...thanks all :)